# Rudin functional analysis theorem 3.28, $P$ is weak*-compact in $C(Q)^*$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

Follow up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130013/rudin-functional-analysis-theorem-3-28-application-of-reisz-representation-theo).

It is later proved that defining $\phi : C(Q)^* \to X$ as
$$
\phi(\mu) = \int_Q x d \mu (x)
$$

if $P$ is the set of all regular probability measures on $Q$ we have $ H \subset \phi(P) \subset \overline{H}$, therefore to prove the equality we have to show that $\phi(P)$ is closed in $X$. One fact needed to show this is

> (i) P is weak*-compact in $C(Q)^*$

The proof starts by noticing

$$
P \subset \left\{ \mu : \left| \int_Q h d\mu \right| \leq 1 \; \text{if} \; \lVert h \rVert < 1 \right\}
$$

As usual I'm sure the observation is very trivial and I'm missing it...
Could you please elaborate the details explaining the inclusion?

All the rest concerning (i) seems fine.

Update:

I think if we assume $\lVert h \rVert < 1$ we can write

$$
1 = \mu(Q) > \lVert h \rVert < 1 \mu(Q) = \int_Q \lVert h \rVert d \mu > \int_Q \left| h \right| d \mu > \left| \int_Q h d \mu \right|
$$

Bearing in mind that every integral involved in this chain of inequalities is a standard lebesgue integral.

Comment: Does $\|h\|$ denote the $\sup$-norm of $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\|h\|$ denotes the $\sup$-norm of $h$, we have that $$\bigg |\int_Q h d\mu \bigg| \leq \int_Q |h| d \mu \leq \int_Q \|h\| d\mu = \|h\| \mu(Q) = \|h\|$$
for $\mu \in P$, since $P$ contains only probability measures on $Q$. Hence, if $\|h\| < 1$ and $\mu \in P$ then $$\bigg |\int_Q h d\mu \bigg| \leq 1$$ as desired.

Comment: Are you sure you can bound the abs of the integral with integral of the abs?

Comment: Yes, this is an elementary property of the lebesgue integral. For simple functions it's just the triangle inequality and then is extended by the usual suite of convergence/approximation arguments.

Comment: The result you're using is proved in the next theorem 3.29. Unless it isn't related.

Comment: Ah, there is just a lot of missing context in this question. I had to actually find a copy of Rudin to see the definition of the integral being used (this isn't just automatic from context, I'd suggest next time you include this kind of important detail). Since this isn't the Lebesgue integral the proof of this property in this answer doesn't work. But yes, you can just use theorem 3.29.

Comment: My apologies, I've asked so many questions about this chapter xD. Anyway I think it is possible to prove the inclusion without using theorem 3.29 I'd find it weird if the author would use a theorem before proving it (at least given what I've been studying so far).

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could prove the inclusion without essentially proving Theorem 3.29. You want to make use of the norm bound $\|h\| \leq 1$ so you really need to be able to put an absolute value inside the integral.

Comment: I find it strange, the author specifically says "to prove (i) note that...", I think if he wanted to use the theorem 3.29 he'd have mentioned it specifically.

Comment: It's actually a bit strange because $\left| \int_Q h d \mu \right|$ isn't exactly defined, in terms of what it means.

Comment: Hi sorry, I think you were right and I might have just confused you. The integral is a standard Lebesgue integral. There's a linked question in my question where basically it allows me to say that $h \in C(Q)$ which is the banach space of continuous real functions on $Q$ with the supremum norm. I think your original derivation was correct and you don't need the theorem 3.29. But I'd be happy if someone other than me can confirm.

Comment: You're right. Sorry I got confused but this is just the Lebesgue integral $\int_Q h(x) d\mu(x)$ where $h(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and hence everything just works out by properties of that integral. I've rolled back my edit so the answer is the original version.